# get name of failed constraint for resolving

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, unique-constraint

During the syncing of multimaster database between android sqlite and sql server, I need to resolve failed unique constraints on android. I have already created sqlite database in android with all the primary key, foreign key and unique constraints in it.

This is an example of one sample table.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + Tables.ARTIST + " ("
            + BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER,"
            + ArtistColumns.ID + " TEXT NULL,"
            + ArtistColumns.MODELTYPE + " TEXT NULL,"
            + ArtistColumns.NAME + " TEXT NULL,"
            + "FOREIGN KEY (" + ArtistColumns.MODELTYPE + ") " + References.MODELTYPE_ID + ","
            + "unique(" + ArtistColumns.MODELTYPE + "," + ArtistColumns.NAME + ")"
            + "PRIMARY KEY(" + ArtistColumns.ID + "))");
```

I am using contentprovider for database operations. In the insert method in provider, I can catch an exception for failed constraint by catching SQLiteConstraintException. But I need to know how I can get the name of unique constraint that failed so that I can resolve the conflict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recent enough SQLite versions show the constraint name in the error message.

On Android, the SQLite version is unlikely to be recent enough.
You have to check the possible field values manually.

Comment: Even when I get error for conflict in android debug log, it shows name of constraint failed in exception message. So I thought it might be possible to get the same programmatically.

Comment: If you are sure that any Android device your app can run on has a recent enough SQLite, then you can try to extract the constraint name from the error message. (The message might change in future versions.)

Comment: I prestored the constraints for each table in sqlite as suggested in accepted answer and then checked for which constraint failed.